# Eclipse Checkstyle Plugin installed but not visible

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, checkstyle

I have installed the plugin checkstyle 6.2.0 in Eclipse Java EE Kepler 4.3.2  , but I am not able to see the Checkstyle option under Windows -> Preferences.

Checkstyle is getting displayed in the installed software list.

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I uninstalled checkstyle 6.2.0 and installed Checkstyle 5.6.1 version.This worked for me.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipse-cs/files/updatesite/5.6.1/

Comment: this works for me, I use Eclipse Luna 4.4.2. win7 64bit.

Comment: Worked also for me in Juno 4.2.1. win7 64bit.

Comment: I had to downgrade from 7.2 to 6.19; Mars.2 (4.5.2), debian 64 bit